# Dynamically add/remove div in knockout attr

Tags: knockout.js

I have two observables 
1.Data and 
2.Image(Making Ajax call to get the image. For this i am passing data Id).
If image is found then i need to display the image and data as shown in below.
For eg :

```
<div class="MainDiv">
        <div class="ImageDiv"><img id="img"  src:"/...image/" /></div>
        <div class="dataDiv" data-bind="text: data/>
</div>
```

suppose if image is not found then i need to hide the image div like

```
<div class="MainDiv">
        /* Hide this when no image  <div class="ImageDiv"><img src="" /> */
        <div class="dataDiv" data-bind="text: data/>
</div>
```

I used ko attr as shown in below:
Var ImageFound contains boolean value. If true display image div & data div else display only data div.

```
<div  data-bind="attr: { class: ImageFound ? 'ImageDiv' : 'DataDiv' }">.
```

Can you please suggest how to do this?

Here is the viewModel code:

```
 // This function internally makes Ajax call for every data to get the corresponding image

        function LoadImages(result) {
            $.each(result, function (id, data) {
                if (data.ImageUrl != null) {
                    return http.get(Url +'/?imageId=' + data.ImageUrl)
                    .success(function (imageResponse) {

                        if (imageResponse == null || imageResponse == "") {
                        newItem.ImageFound= false;
                        }else {
                            var newItem = vm.Data()[id];
                            newItem.Image = "" + imageResponse;
                            newItem.ImageFound= true;
                            vm.data.replace(vm.data()[id],newItem)
                            vm.data(result);
                        }
                    })
                    .fail(function (exception) { });
```

Answer (score 0):

If ImageFound is an observable, then you need to call it as one:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { class: ImageFound() ? 'ImageDiv' : 'DataDiv' }">
```

Otherwise all you are doing is resolving whether the observable (which is just a function, as far as javascript is concerned) exists. And it always will exist, therefore will always resolve to true.

Comment: ImageFound is not an observable. its a boolean variable to check the condtion for image found r not.

Comment: Show your viewmodel code to understand your binding on ImageFound

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `visible` binding like this :

```
<div class="MainDiv">
  <div class="ImageDiv" data-bind="visible: ImageFound()">
    <img id="img"  src:"/...image/" />
  </div>
  <div class="dataDiv" data-bind="visible: !ImageFound(), text: data"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.ImageFound is not a function. Inside viewModel i have written a Ajax function where i am passing dataId to get the image and checking the condition like Image is null or empty. if null or empty i am assging true/ false to the variable ImageFound.As i am new to KO i am not sure this is correct or not. For checking the condition. can we use ko.computed??

Comment: Is the variable ImageFound an observable ? Because if it is you have to use ImageFound(), not ImageFound. If it's not an observable, then you are right, you should use ImageFound.

Comment: There is problem with data binding. In viewmodel below  code vm.data.replace(vm.data()[id],newItem). After calling this replace function ImageFound data is not binding.

Comment: Please make a fiddle, otherwise I can't help you.